# Running cytoscape in HPC, how to increase performance?

Tags: cytoscape

I'm helping a user get setup with Cytoscape on our HPC and I'm wondering if there are ways besides the opencl support to get higher performance from Cytoscape. What I mean is I have a 94 cpu node that seems to be running one of the layout operations of a sample dataset in almost the same speed as the user's desktop machine.

I can tell by looking in the `Cytoscape.vmoptions` that the HPC memory available is being provided to the program so I don't think that's what's preventing higher performance. If opencl is the requirement for multicpu core leverage then I'll try to work that out, but I thought it was mostly for leveraging the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is that "it depends".  If the network is heavily partitioned, then the individual partitions are laid out in parallel.  If it is a single partition, then most of the force directed algorithms don't parallelize well, unfortunately.